# Display two previous posts on single.php

Tags: php, posts, previous

At the bottom of single.php, I want to display "card" links to the next and previous posts in chronological order. This is pretty easy thanks to `get_next_post()` and `get_previous_post`, no problems so far.

However, I want to change that feed when on the most recent post -- that post won't have a next post. Instead of an empty space in my layout, I'd like to display the previous post ***and its previous post.*** So the two previous posts instead of just one.

I know how to check if we're on the most recent post, I'm just not sure how to properly call the multiple previous posts. My basic code structure is:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
          // output current post here
     }

     $next = get_next_post();
     if( $next ) {
          $id = $next->ID;
          $url = get_the_permalink( $id );
          $title = $next->post_title;
          $date = get_the_date( '', $next );
          // use these variables to output link to next post
     }

     $prev = get_previous_post();
     if( $prev ) {
          $id = $prev->ID;
          $url = get_the_permalink( $id );
          $title = $prev->post_title;
          $date = get_the_date( '', $prev );
          // use these variables to output link to previous post
     }

     // If there's no next post, that means we're on the most recent post.
     // To fill the space, let's pull the 2nd previous post.
     if( !$next ) {
          // Make sure there's a previous post
          if( $prev ) {

               // Conditions are perfect. Now how do I grab that 2nd previous post??

          }
     }
 }
```

I'm sure it's some basic query issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope there are multiple ways to accomplish this, but I suggest you use the following simpler function for this purpose. This is an attempt to grab a post for the current post which excludes it and the previous post:

```php
// A custom function in your functions.php file
function get_related_previous_post($previous = 0) {

    global $post; // take current post object
    $category_ids = array();
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID); // current post categories
    
    if ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $individual_category) {
            $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
        }
    }

    $args = array(
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID, $previous), // exclude posts
        'posts_per_page' => '1',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'category__in' => $category_ids // apply same categories 
    );
    $prevprev_id = 0;
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();
            // Do your stuff
            $prevprev_id = $post->ID;
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return get_post($prevprev_id);
}
```

Call the function in your `single.php` file like:

```
if (!$next) {
    // Make sure there's a previous post
    if ($prev) {
        $prevprev = get_related_previous_post($prev->ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is a really smart solution and looks like it will do what I need it to. Will post again once I've figured out how to adapt to the rest of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I'm getting stuck on the implementation. This will echo the correct post ID, so the query is good. 

What I really need to do is store the post object as a variable, so I can choose what to echo where. Ideally it would work the same as `$next = get_next_post();` so that in single.php I'd be able to do something like `$related = get_related_previous_post($prev->ID);`

That way I'd be able to grab and echo the parts of `$related` I want, like I can with `$next` and `$prev`. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Since you have the ID of the prev/prev post, we need to return the post object. Save the ID in a variable and take the post object with the get_post function and return at the end of the function. 

    ...
    $prevprev_id = 0;
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();

            echo $post->ID;
            $prevprev_id = $post->ID;
            // Do your stuff
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return get_post($prevprev_id);

Comment: Updated the main message. Hope you find a clue about returning the object

Comment: That did it! Thanks again for all your help!